Can not install Plugin.InAppBilling in .Net Maui project
I have a .Net Maui project that is compiling fine, when I install the nuget plugin: Plugin.InAppBilling I can no longer compile the project and I receive this error:

A referenced assembly was compiled using a newer version of
Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.dll. Please update to a newer .NET SDK in
order to reference this assembly.

How can I solve this problem?


What version of Plugin.InAppBilling you are using and also what platform you are testing it? 2. Have you installed package Microsoft.Bcl.Build, if so, can you try to uninstall it and see if it helps?


In installed the latest version at today is 8.0.5, I am targeting Windows platform, I have not installed Microsoft.Bcl.Build package on my project.

The only solution that I have found is to downgrade the package Plugin.InAppBilling from version 8.0.5 to version 7.1.3
